# Convert a byte into 8 bits with true or false flags

Tags: c#, .net, byte, bit, bitarray

I am trying to read a `byte` and convert into a `bit`. I am trying to create a flagging system.

So byte 3 would be raise the first two flags as true. However When I try and convert it just passes the value of the `byte` as the length of the `BitArray`. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(filestream);

Byte flag = br.ReadByte();

BitArray flags = new BitArray(flag); 

record.Isbool = flags[0];
record.Isbool1 = flags[1];

etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new BitArray(flag);` uses the `BitArray(Int32 length)` constructor. This sets the capacity, not what you want.

You can use

```
    new BitArray(new byte[] { flag });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
BitArray flags = new BitArray(new byte[] {flag});
```

The `byte[]` overload uses the bits from the bytes; at the moment you're calling the `int` overload which gives the length as you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(filestream);

Byte flag = br.ReadByte();

BitArray flags = new BitArray(new byte[] {flag}); 

record.Isbool = flags[0];
record.Isbool1 = flags[1];
```

Should work, by invoking the [`BitArray(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a.aspx) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to mask.  int flag = value & 0x01  to mask the 1st bit.